# Spinner DatePicker does not change text color

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to change the text color from the `DatePicker` using an XML style with no luck. My app theme is `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` and the style code that I am using is the following.

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" >
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    style="@style/MyDatePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

I have seen many posts tackling this issue, but unfortunately  none of the answers worked for me. I am using version `1.2.0` of the material library.

Is there any other way to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DatePicker ***is a*** ViewGroup, you apply the defined style to it (and its children) using the `theme` attribute.

`style`, in contrast, is applied to the parent DatePicker only and its children remain unaffected.

So change to:

```
android:theme="@style/MyDatePicker"
```